# how a definition for an object is arrived

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, philosophy-of-language

is our definitions of words based in properties ? for example we have a banana.We define banana from its image? but if this true if we find something that looks like banana but smells like hot dog then it is a banana? but even if we give banana some properties these properties come arbitrary..so how we define something ?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because, quite plainly, you got nothing from it. I hope someone else is able to respond more informatively.

Comment: The 3 most important thinkers to help you understand this are , Derrida, Derrida and Derrida.

Comment: We do **not** define bananas... We learn how to identify and use bananas

Comment: Maybe useful: [Natural Kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/).

Comment: "but even if we give banana some properties these properties come arbitrary..so how we define something ?" What do you mean by giving the banana properties; do you mean something like ascribing properties to the banana? Why would this be an arbitrary process?

Answer (score 0):

A definition describes the area which collects risk and opportunity in relation to a given goal. The properties included in a definition depend on the definition's purpose.

If the purpose is to illustrate a children’s book of colors, it is sufficient to show how a banana has a certain shape and is yellow. If the purpose is to place a banana scientifically among all plants, it is necessary to say that one banana tree species is, for example, *Musa acuminata*. If the purpose is to ship bananas from the forest to the store, it is necessary to describe the degree of ripeness before the banana can be harvested and sold.